# Doit-on écrire « projeter des vidéos YouTube sur un téléviseur » ou « projeter des vidéos YouTube à la télévision » ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Je regarde actuellement une série Netflix sur mon téléviseur.

Je regarde actuellement une série Netflix à la télévision.

Ou encore:

Je regarde actuellement sur mon téléviseur une série diffusée par Netflix.

Je regarde actuellement à la télévision une série diffusée par Netflix.

La difficulté sur laquelle je bute réside dans le fait que les séries et les films Netflix ne sont pas diffusés par des ondes Hertziennes mais par des ondes/signaux électriques ou lumineuses (internet). Si le support qu’on utilise pour regarder du contenu télévisé qui requiert internet est un téléviseur, peut-on tout de même dire à la télévision ?

Devrait-on dire « projeter des vidéos YouTube à la télévision » ou « projeter des vidéos YouTube sur un téléviseur » ?

D’autres variantes à proposer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Doit-on écrire « projeter des vidéos YouTube sur un téléviseur » ou « projeter des vidéos YouTube à la télévision » ?*

Ni l'un ni l'autre puisqu'il n'y a pas de projecteur, l'image étant générée par l'écran lui-même.

On dit en revanche couramment:

> Regarder/visionner des vidéos YouTube sur une télé / une télévision / un téléviseur
> Regarder des vidéos YouTube sur l'écran de sa télé.
> Regarder des vidéos YouTube sur sa télé.

et donc:

> En ce moment, je regarde une série Netflix sur ma télé.

Que ce soit du direct, du différé, un film diffusé par une chaîne généraliste ou une vidéo à la demande n'a pas d'influence sur le nom que l'on donne au dispositif utilisé pour l'afficher.

On peut très bien dire qu'on regarde un film muet sur son téléphone ou écoute la radio sur sa télévision sans que l'incohérence étymologique ne choque personne.

Answer (score 0):

Si c'est la TV qui peut jouer des vidéos YouTube :

> Regarder des vidéos Youtube sur un téléviseur

Si c'est du "streaming" depuis un autre appareil :

> Diffuser des vidéos Youtube sur un téléviseur

"Diffuser *à la* télévision" indiquerait qu'on a une influence sur la chaîne ou le média télévisuel (faire passer quelque chose à la télévision, programmer une émission à la télévision) et pas l'appareil qu'on a chez soi.

Answer (score -1):

Qu'il s'agisse d'une transmission par ondes dans l'espace (antennes), par cables (courants) ou dans un conducteur (fibre optique) il n'y a pas de différence : l'information est toujours transmise d'un point éloigné, ce que le préfixe  Grec « tele » (loin) rend dans le mot « télévision ». « Télévision » n'est pas un terme qui a signifié strictement « voir ce qui se passe au loin », puisque en plus des programmes en direct, c'est à dire des programmes qui sont la reproduction visuelle presque instantanée de ce qui se passe à des dizaines ou des centaines de kilomètres, il a existé depuis la création de la télévision la possibilité de transmettre des enregistrements vidéos (films, documentaires, enregistrements quelconques) ; il est évident que dans ces cas-là, rien ne se passe à distance et qu'il n'existe qu'une transmission de codes ; il ne s'agit donc plus vraiment de « vision à distance ». Ceci s'est révélé à l'esprit de façon plus frappante encore lorsque les magnétoscopes ont plus tard fait leur apparition ; il ne s'agit plus d'une transmission à partir d'un organisme qui est très éloigné mais à partir d'un appareil très proche, le magnétoscope  (dans la même pièce), sur lequel ont été enregistrés des programmes TV. L'appareil de télévision n'est plus qu'un transformateur de codes ou signaux—c'est à dire qu'on n'utilse que la partie qui transforme un signal—et ses fonctions de récepteur ne sont plus mises à contribution.

Il s'ensuit que ni « à la télévision » ni « sur le téléviseur » ne sont vraiment appropriés.  Dans le cas  des vidéos Youtube il n'y a rien de différent et un terme correct serait un terme qui exprimerait la fonction de reception des signaux et celle de leur transformation en un effet physique, la  lumière et le son qui peuvent changer en continu.

On a pendant un certain temps utilisé le terme « récepteur radio » et « récepteur » sans aucune spécification de la fonction de transformation qu'a un appareil radio. On utilise encore le mot « récepteur » pour « télévision » (long terme : récepteur de télévision). Ce terme serait donc plus approprié, mais toujours pas un terme qui cernerait l'essentiel de la fonction dont il s'agit vraiment.

Comment: Merci LPH pour cette réponse très détaillée. Que devrait-on dire et écrire pour être respectueux du bon usage? ou plutôt qu’écririez-vous en ce cas ?

Comment: @LPH c'est peut-être inexact techniquement mais "projeter sur un téléviseur" ne me choque pas.

Comment: @Thérèse Je n'utiliserais pas « projeter » mais plutôt un verbe comme « passer ».  « je regarde …  sur mon télévisuer » ou « je regarde … à la télévision » sont les formes les plus acceptables.